# How stop Macbook White to try to find a CD

Tags: macos, dvd

I have a very annoying problem. My old Mac Book White with OS X Lion try to find if there is a CD/DVD every X minutes.

The problem is because it cause a noise. If I put a CD/DVD inside it, from time to time it start to read the disk.

Maybe it happens because I share the CD/DVD device with network. This is annoying. I only want to check the disk when I try to read it.

How can I stop it?

One solution is unplug the ethernet cable. It worked now. But... There is another solution?

Comment: If you turn off DVD sharing, does the problem stop? What other devices are on the network?

Comment: Well, after I realize the problem was because the network, maybe if I don't share it I solve the problem... But... This is a problem because I want to share it :D My network has only 3 computer with a simple hub. They all use cables. It has the macbook white, a new mac mini and a windows notebook. Maybe this can happens because the windows computer.

Comment: I'm not saying don't use the sharing feature, we're just trying to get to the bottom of the issue. Perhaps also try to enable the "ask for permission to use drive" option and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @KevinGrabher, lol. Great idea. I will try to configure it and wait some time to see if it stop.

Comment: did you try to remove it from Spotlight indexing (search)?

Comment: No, great idea too. I will do it.

Comment: @Buscar웃, until now this was the best solution. When I try the Kevin Grabher tips, the problem was I can't access the DVD easily in the other computer. But when I just remove the DVD from Spotlight, it really stop to try to access it. This happens with and without the DVD inserted in the device. Let's see if it continue in this way.

Comment: Ok than, you are happy, lets make it a answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the Spotlight indexing (search) for the DVD it should stop pestering you with the message.

Comment: Lol, now I discovery something. The problem happens when I make the computer sleep. When the DVD slot is empty, the mac book try to read it from time to time. I just turn off the Spotlight but not the DVD share. I will test more and see it it happens when the ethernet cable is off.